# Type of file in Python

Tags: python, file-type

I am looking for a function in Python to determine the type of a file.
I mean, the input is the path where the file is located, and the output is the type.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you call type, to the extension?

Comment: Please, provide example of input and output. Do you need `pathlib.PurePath.suffix` method?

Answer (score 0):

If looking at the extension is enough, [`mimetypes.guess_type()`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/mimetypes.html#mimetypes.guess_type) is your friend.

For more robust identification, you might want to look at [`python-magic`](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic).

Answer (score 0):

The Python Magic library provides the functionality you need.

You can install the library with `pip install python-magic` and use it as follows:

```
>>> import magic
>>> magic.from_file('filename')
```